# Plastic SCM remote checked files

Tags: plasticscm

I've problem view status/checked files from other PC.

[image: Status from two PC]
I need view if is file checked in another PC. I go from Perforce, then hadn't problem with this synchronisation.

Answer (score 2):

The Plastic SCM "checkout" is a local workspace operation (client side).
The server (and the other workspaces) are not aware of this local operation.

If you want to use the the checkout operation as exclusive checkout (or lock), you need to configure it following the next steps:

https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/administration/plastic-scm-version-control-administrator-guide.shtml#Chapter6:ConfiguringExclusiveCheckout(Lock)

Once it's configured, the system performs the following operations:

- Is the file locked? If so, it can't be checked out.
- If it isn't locked, the file is potentially "lockable". Plastic SCM will check whether the file name matches any of the rules defined on lock.conf. If the file name matches the rules, the file will be locked.

Comment: I it see now, lock.conf is in server :) but information about locking is not visualised.

Comment: You can run "cm listlocks". If you use the Gluon GUI you can also get this information from the graphical interface: https://www.plasticscm.com/documentation/gluon/plastic-scm-version-control-gluon-guide.shtml#Butarethefilesreallylocked?